# Cannot implement next() method throught iterator

Tags: java, interface

I am trying to implement the next() method through an interface, however it is giving me an error. Here is what I have:

```
private class MyIterator implements Iterator<Term>
{

    private final Polynomial myArray;
    private int current;

    MyIterator(Polynomial myArray) {
        this.myArray = myArray;
        this.current = myArray.degree;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current < myArray.degree;
    }


    @Override
    public Integer next() { //this method right here does not work
        if (! hasNext())   throw new UnsupportedOperationException();;
        return myArray.coeff[current++];
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

The next() method then throws me this error :

[image: error]

And this is my interface:

```
public interface Term {

int coeff();
int exp();
String toString();
}
```

So my question is why the interface does not allow the MyIterator to implement the next() method

Comment: Okay, reading and understanding the error message would have explained the problem. But downvoting? How many times have you not looked and your log files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your class is implementing `Iterator<Term>`, so `next()` must return a `Term`, not an `Integer`.

**Edit:** This line

```
if (! hasNext())   throw new UnsupportedOperationException();;
```

is wrong. If the `Iterator` has no more items, [`next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next%28%29) must throw a [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html).

Comment: Thanks, I believe I will have to make it implement integer instead of Term

Answer (score 1):

The `Iterator<Term>` promises that your iterator will return references of type `Term`, but your `next()` method attempts to return `Integer`.

One of the two things needs to change to be consistent with the other one.